# How to create a sequence field that is equal for duplicates and unique only for unique rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, etl, data-warehouse

I'm extracting data from several databases and want to keep track of duplicate records without purging them. My solution is to create a new sequence field, where rows are marked duplicate by having the same sequence number. Keep in mind that not all columns have to be equal to be considered a duplicate.

How do I do this? My goal is to have this table with all duplicate records intact, and finally another table where I would only have unique records by merging those with same sequence ID.

Comment: Not sure if I have understood.

Comment: You can [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) your records by whatever numerical criteria you need and use the result as [sequence ID].

Comment: You wouldn't necessarily have to rank them at all in order to select a particular row which duplicates the sequence id, but it would depend on your criterion for merging them, is there a "most recent version of the sequence id" or other criterion by which you would select a specific duplicate to appear in the de-duplicated table?

Comment: Just how does this magic merge work where "not all columns have to be equal to be considered a duplicate".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t.*, Sequence_ID=DENSE_RANK() over (
                order by <fields_you_want_to_test_for_uniqueness>
            )
from <your_table> t
```

Note that DENSE_RANK() gives you identical values for a "tie", but also gives you consecutive numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 3, 4), whereas RANK() gives you the same value for a "tie", but then skips numbers (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 3, 5). Choose whichever one suits your needs.